# How to click on Internet Explorer's security prompt for downloads programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, security, internet-explorer

We are developing an internal application that uses C# to automate user actions on a website in order to download a txt file. We have been stuck for a couple of weeks on a requirement that is: at the end of the process, the bot needs to click on "OK" when I.E. prompts (security question) if you are sure you want to download this specific file from the site.
This security prompt is not on the website, and we have considered using technologies like "SendKeys", but we need to determine the pixels on which the button is located in order to click on it.

Comment: What is the context of this request? Where is this file located?  Behind a website that expires?  Is the URI static?  Does the vendor provide an API?

Comment: The whole point of having the Security Question Prompt is to do human intervention and prevent any automated program from clicking such security prompts. You should explore other options like putting the site URL in the trusted list and playing around with the Browser settings.

Comment: @Kyle This is part of a bot that inputs info into the website via C# WebBrowser and navigates to this form, where we need to download a file as the final step of the process.

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee I understand, however this is a automation within a safe corporate environment. We already solved it using "UI Path" (RPA), but we need to replace that solution with custom code. If "UI Path" was written in .Net I would argue that why can't we do the same with custom C# code.

Comment: @MarianoPeinador I don't understand... Why is there a need for UI interaction if you want to do this programmatically at all?  If it's an internal site and all you care about are basic inputs, just `POST` those directly via an API, no?

Comment: @Kyle yes, but after that, we need to programmatically simulate the user's "click" on the Internet Explorer "Security Prompt" for file download. Security policies in the company don't allow us to change the security settings for this prompt, but we have a Windows Forms with admin rights, so we are looking for a way to click on this sneeky button.